# PHP 5.5 : how to convert array with 1 element to property of parent

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel

I have this:

```
$foo = Foo::getFooById(100);

public static function getFooById($id)
{
    return Foo::where('id', $id)->with('locations')->firstOrFail();
}
```

This returns an Eloquent collection.

$foo gives now the following properties:

```
$foo->name
$foo->locations
```

$foo->locations is an array with always 1 element

Just I want:

```
$foo->location = $foo->locations[0];
unset($foo->locations);
```

This code works, but is very terrible, because it happens on different places. How can I do this in a clear way?

Comment: Can you show your `getFooById` method?

Comment: I just updated my question with the method getFooById

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown it, but I assume you've defined Foo as having a one-to-many relationship with locations.

If there is always just a single location for any given Foo, then you should define it with a one-to-one relationship rather than one-to-many, then you'll be able to say `$foo->location` to get the single location object rather than `$foo->locations` to get an array of them.

In other words, I guess you have code in your `Foo` model that looks like this:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('locations');
}
```

You need to replace it with something more like this:

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->hasOne('locations');
}
```

Then change `with('locations')` in your query function to `with('location')`.

Comment: yes I know, but I've multiple other objects with locations. That's why I save locations separate and use linking tables between both. In Eloquent (Laravel), I cannot use one-to-many with linking table. That's why I use this construction.

Comment: You should include details like that in the question; there was nothing in the question showing how your relationships work. If you want to keep the old relationship as well, the easiest way would be `function location() { return $this->locations[0];}`. Or you could specify both one-to-one and one-to-many relationships in the class and use whichever one is appropriate each time. Or have two model classes for `Foo` extending off a shared base class, one with `location` and the other with `locations`. If none of that is helpful, please edit the question to give more details of what you're doing.